# Get custom property from a button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have this button in HTML , with a property defined by me on it  (data-filter-params):

```
<button class="button" type="submit" data-filter-params="{'Type', 'Filter.Type'},{'Code','Filter.Code'}" >Filter</button>
```

How can I take with JavaScript\JQuery the value for data-filter-params

Comment: `$('button').data('filter-params')`

Comment: `$('button').attr('data-filter-params')`

Comment: Whatever method you'll use here, you'll get a string, is it really what you are expecting???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it

```
var value
$(function(){
   value = $('button').attr('data-filter-params')
})
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/3k97gg9k/

Answer (score 1):

plain javascript

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
console.log(btn.dataset.filterParams)
```

jQuery

```
console.log($('.button').data('filter-params'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy,

HTML:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" data-filter-params="{'Type', 'Filter.Type'},{'Code','Filter.Code'}" >Filter</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var attr = $('#btnSubmit').attr('data-filter-params');

alert(attr)
```